# .net 8 parallel optimization

Tags: .net, optimization, parallel-processing

Scope: minimize execution time of a big data workflow by optimizing the code for parallelism.
When it comes to running complex computations over big amount of data, ensuring that the code is optimal to use at best the available computation resources become critical.
in .NET there are multiple ways to write parallel code (e.g. Parallel.For, Tasks...).
To get the optimal performance, though, using the parallel primitives offerd by the framework is hardly enough. More often than not, it is crucial that the code is also written with particular attention to minimize contentions and races.
Visual Studio offers profiling tools that help in this task, for example the [Concurrency Visualizer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConcurrencyVisualizer2022)
What is quite nebulous to me is what happens when the optimized code is deployed to a production environment completely different from the development one. Let's  make an example:

- Development: Visual Studio 2022 on a Window 10 machine with 16 cores
- Production: Linux container with ASP.NET 8 image and 96 cores into an AKS cluster

In such a scenario, questions arise that I cannot find answers to:

1. Can we be confident that the effort spent in optimizing code for parallel execution using the development environment is preserved in the production deployment?

The code has been optimized in Windows, which is different from Linux. Moreover, once the production container is running in AKS, there is no way to use the profiling tools we used in the development machine to check what's going on.

2. Is there a way to get coherent metrics between the two environments?

Let's make a specific example:
When I run my code in the development machine, I can open task manager and look at the CPU utilization. What I see is that all the 16 cores go to high utilization. This makes me think that there a good level of parallelism.
Once the code is in the production environment, there is not a task manager to open. The available metrics are the top commands in linux and the Azure portal metrics tools. However, when I look at those, I get an indication of only 20% of CPU utilization (cumulative, not per core), which is totally different from what I would expect (which is rather closer to 100%) as with the development.

If someone has experience in these topics, any hints or clue is much appreciated.